# The record keyword in java is convenient. What is the most similar mutable option to easily create a class?

Tags: java

Using a record seems like a very convenient way to create a basic class. However, it is immutable. Is there a similar keyword that creates a class that can be changed?

In other words, is there a way to create a basic class without typing it all out by hand?

Comment: Note that records are not *necessarily* deeply immutable. A record member can be a mutable `List`, for example. [AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/value/userguide/index.md) and [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) are two different approaches to provide what you want, but both are external solutions, there's no language-level support for fully-mutable "simply types". Personally I dislike Lombok, due to the way it's implemented, but AFAIK it's more popular than AutoValue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.